# Incorrect assignment of values in char enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I was playing with enums and tried to reproduce some examples [from this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) page. Initial examples worked as intended, however I got some interesting results with following code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum num : char {
    zero = '0',
    one = '1',
    two = '2',
    three = '3',
    four = '4',
    five = '5',
    six = '6'
};

int main()
{
    const char two = '2';
    std::cout << two << std::endl;
    std::cout << num::two;
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> 2
>   50

I expected both outcomes to be the same, but the `num::two` seems to print some other value. Also this value doesn't changes`(50)`, so I assume this isn't a random/garbage value & there is some sort of char/int parsing being done that I don't understand? Here is [the ideone link](http://ideone.com/gSn9Md).

I know that I can make it work by assigning like this `zero = 0`, without single quotes and it works. However, I want to know what is happening behind the scenes and how could I control what non-single digits value I can print via single quotes assignments.

Comment: [ASCII - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: @Drop I was assuming this as well but then why does `const char two = '2';` works as intended? Both use single quotes assignment and that's what made it more confusing.

Comment: What does that have to do with assignment? Your title should be asking to explain the reason for the output.

Comment: @JDługosz assignment because same form assignment eg `one = '1'` & `char c = '1'` produces different outputs, and at the time of writing this question I overlooked the operator overloading part. Had I known the answer, why would I have posted it here?

Comment: Actually, neither of those uses of `=` is assignment.  Since the question is of more general interest then you originally expected, you might edit the title.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This should actually go to the `char` overload now; unfortunately none of the compilers at issue implement [DR 1601](http://wg21.link/cwg1601).

[[conv.prom]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#4):

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>   fixed ([dcl.enum]) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying
>   type.

This means `num` can be promoted to `char`.

> Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying
>   type, a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type
>   is fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying
>   type.

So `num` can be promoted to `int`, too.

The relevant candidates are:

```
template <class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        char ch );
template<class charT, class Traits>
basic_ostream<charT, Traits>& basic_ostream<charT, Traits>::operator<<(int);
```

For both candidates, the first argument is an identity conversion and the second is a promotion. Both `num` to `char` and `num` to `int` have promotion rank.

Pre-DR1601, these are equally as good, so the template/non-template tiebreaker comes in. The first one is a function template; the second one is a plain member function, so the second one wins.

DR1601 added a rule that says:

> A conversion that promotes an enumeration whose underlying type is
>   fixed to its underlying type is better than one that promotes to the
>   promoted underlying type, if the two are different.

This means that `num` to `char` is now better than `num` to `int`, so the first overload is now a better match and should be selected.

Comment: this is for `c++14`, yes?

Comment: @bolov The change is a DR against C++11, so should be retroactive.

Comment: @StoryTeller http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#4.2 is the new wording. I see it in C++14

Answer (score 14):

According to the C++ Standard (4.5 Integral promotions)

> 4 A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is
>   fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type.
>   **Moreover, if integral promotion can be applied to its underlying type,
>   a prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed can also be converted to a prvalue of the promoted underlying
>   type**.

So the integral promotion is applied and the operator << for objects of type int is called.

Answer (score 10):

When you say `enum num : char`, then you express the fact that `num` is internally implemented in terms of a `char` but can still be automatically converted to an integer value, which is *not* necessarily `char`.

As the page you cite says:

> Values of unscoped enumeration type are implicitly-convertible to
>   integral types.

See [Why does a value of an enum with a fixed underlying type of char resolve to fct(int) instead of fct(char)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14206403/why-does-a-value-of-an-enum-with-a-fixed-underlying-type-of-char-resolve-to-fct) for an interesting discussion on problems in the C++ standard's wording regarding the combination of integral promotion and fixed underlying types.

In any case, you can imagine this whole thing like a class with a private `char` member variable and a public `int` conversion operator:

```
// very similar to your enum:
class num {
private:
    char c;

public:
    num(char c) : c(c) {}
    operator int() const {
        return c;
    }
};

num two { '2' };
std::cout << two; // prints 50
```

To increase type safety and make the `std::cout` line a compilation error, just turn the `enum` into an `enum class`:

```
enum class num : char
```

This is again similar to the imagined `class num` above, but without the conversion operator.

When you feed an instance of `num` to `std::cout`, then you are a client of `num` and are not logically supposed to think that the output format will take its internal `char` implementation into account.

To get more control over the output format, you should instead do like with any other custom type, and overload `operator<<` for `std::ostream`. Example:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class num : char {
    zero = '0',
    one = '1',
    two = '2',
    three = '3',
    four = '4',
    five = '5',
    six = '6'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, num const& n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case num::zero: os << "Zero"; break;
        case num::one: os << "One"; break;
        case num::two: os << "Two"; break;
        case num::three: os << "Three"; break;
        // and so on
    }
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << num::two; // prints "Two"
}
```

Of course, the specific `char` values of the enum instances have now become pretty useless, so you may as well get rid of them completely:

```
enum class num : char {
    zero,
    one,
    two,
    three,
    four,
    five,
    six
};
```

This may strike you as strange, but keep in mind that an enum which represents nothing but generic numbers from zero to six is not a realistic use case.

Comment: Nice detailed explanation; however (for style points) I would encourage switching the implementation of `operator<<` to a `switch` statement instead. Compilers generate warnings for switches that fail to handle all enumerators (if you forego the `default` case): `swtich(n) { case num::zero: return os << "Zero"; case ... } throw std::runtime_error("Unknown enumerator");`.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: You cannot use `switch` with an enum class.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: My bad. Will change.

Answer (score 7):

Because the two call two different operator overloads:

- the first calls the non-member `operator<<` for `std::ostream` and `char`. This prints the character.
- The second example calls the member `operator<<` for `int` due to integer promotions, as explained by other answers.

Comment: Yep. You have to be really, really careful when combining characters with strings.  "Abc" + '1' will generally compile without issue but most certainly will  not do what you want, leading to a crash.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that your `enum : char` is not the same as `char` (which is exactly what we want - we don't want enum to be the same as other types, even if they are assignment compatible - we want `void func(num n)` to be distinct from `void func(char n)`, right?).

So, since `enum num` isn't a `char`, the `operator<<(int)` will be used, and prints the integer value, even if the underlying type is `char`. Not entirely sensible, but I'm sure this is what happens.